# Qual é a diferença entre "merge" e "fill" no Lucid do AdonisJs?

Tags: adonisjs, lucid

Eu tenho vários anos de experiência com o Laravel e estou dando uma olhada no framework AdonisJs. Ele é bem parecido com o Laravel em vários pontos, porém especificamente estou tendo uma dúvida em relação ao preenchimento de dados de um model Lucid.

Por exemplo, no Laravel eu costumo utilizar o método `fill` para preencher apenas alguns campos desejados através de um `array`, para salvar 
 essas informações.

Eu tentei usar o `fill` no AdonisJS de forma parecida, porém estava aparecendo um erro, como se os outros campos tivessem sido apagados. Quando usei o `merge`, não tive esse problema, o comportalmente foi parecido com o do `fill` do Laravel.

Por exemplo:

```
const usuario = await Usuario.find(1)

usuario.merge({"nome": "Wallace"});

usuario.save(); // Aqui é ok

usuario.fill({"nome" : "Wallace"});

usuario.save(); // Aqui dá erro
```

Diante disso, eu pergunto:

- Qual são as diferenças entre `fill` e `merge` no AdonisJS?
- Quando usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Lucid quando você utiliza o método `fill`, todos os outros valores existentes serão removidos mantendo apenas o que acabou de definir. Você pode utilizar este método quando quiser inserir um registro com valores definidos totalmente no próprio código, por exemplo.

O método `merge` modifica apenas o elemento que você especificou, mantendo todos os outros. Você pode utilizar este método quando quiser modificar/adicionar apenas algum dos atributos que foi enviado.

Você pode conferir a [documentação oficial do Adonis](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_fill_merge) sobre os 2 métodos.

Comment: Não precisa excluir as suas respostas e postar uma nova. Basta editar.